# What do these numbers signify?

Tags: sequences-and-series

During a visit in [Nicosia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicosia) I came across a strange sequence (which was situated in a rather bizarre place). What is the connection between the numbers or what do they signify?

[image: Picture number 1]

[image: Picture number 2]

Comment: Well according to https://oeis.org/ this is not a known mathematical sequence of any consequence.  Maybe it has local historical significance.  Very intriguing.

Comment: OEIS doesn't seem to know this sequence, so I doubt it is something mathematical.

Comment: Well, I didn't knew about this website. I modified the title accordingly.

Comment: Well Puzzling.SE might be useful for you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a piece of "modern art", by Nikos Kouroussis and Constantinos Kalisperas, called "Ipervasi" (Greek for "excess", or "transgression"). It's an old abandoned telecommunication station that used to belong to the UN forces in Cyprus (there was a peacekeeping force set up in 1964 after violent riots and fights between the Turkish and Greek populations on the island). They hanged it on the side of the NiMac ("Nicosia Municipal Arts Centre").

The numbers you can see below refer to all the resolutions passed by the Security Council of the United Nations that have something to do with Cyprus, starting with resolution $186$ - "[The Cyprus Question](http://www.un.org/en/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=S/RES/186(1964))". You can check all the resolutions [here](http://www.un.org/en/sc/documents/resolutions/).

So in a sense, it's a "monument to collapsed endeavours".

Comment: Very interesting thanks.